# #autocomplete_path trigger on focus in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, autocomplete, drupal-7

I want to show some autocomplete option on focus, at the moment '#autocomplete_path' only works when a user types something in the text field.

How can we show some default suggestion moment user click inside the text field?

Answer (score 0):

As I tried a lot using Drupal form API, not able to achieve. Now using JQuery/AJAX and showing dynamic option list onclick.